# Alert dialog not working in Lua

Tags: lua, gideros

I am using Lua with Gideros and having alert box to show up when back button is pressed.According to Gideros documentation, when first button is pressed, it returns index 1 but it does not really seem to work this way.I tested the app on my android phone.I realized the oncomplete function is not getting called at all, since I tried using a print statement and even it was not executed, so any idea why is is not getting called?

```
local function onKeyDown(event)
if event.keyCode == KeyCode.BACK then

        local alertDialog = AlertDialog.new("Confirmation", "Are you sure you want to exit?", "Cancel", "Yes")
        alertDialog:show()
        stage:addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, oncomplete)
        end
end

function oncomplete(e)
if e.buttonIndex == 1 then 
stage:addEventListener(Event.APPLICATION_SUSPEND, suspend)
application: exit()
end

end

function suspend()
application: exit()
end

-- key events are dispatched to all Sprite instances on the scene tree (similar to mouse and touch events)
stage:addEventListener(Event.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown)
```

Comment: How does it work? What are you getting there instead? Are you getting anything there? If not what is happening?

Comment: @EtanReisner: Actually, nothing happens! Alert dialog shows up and when I click on it, no event is dispatching.nothing happens!

Comment: Does the `COMPLETE` event fire on the stage or does it fire on the `alertDialog`?

Comment: Then should you be adding the listener on `stage` or on `alertDialog`?

Comment: @EtanReisner : Oh, yes  :) Thanks a ton :) It worked! Added listener to alertDialog :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the conversation the issue was that the event listener for the alert box close event was being attached to the stage instead of the alert dialog.

`stage:addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, oncomplete)`

instead of

`alertDialog:addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, oncomplete)`